# Spatial Adjustment of shapefile not possible

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, affine-transformation, spatial-adjustment

I am trying to spatially adjust a shapefile containing several polygons to another shapefiles where spatial data is correct. Both should share exactly the same extent. However, when I am using spatial adjustment it never lets me accurately match the two shapefiles based on the displacement links. No matter how many links I set. An obvious shift always remains.

[image: both feature sets never match]

The two shapefiles can be seen HERE:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10mcprmxrLFzUnYRYILZwE5hAO6bcuNGe?usp=sharing

"PopDensity" is the one that needs to match the correct "statistische_gebiete"-shapefile.

Any clue what I am doing wrong? Or is my understanding wrong that the spatial adjustment scales, rotates and shifts whole shapefiles?

Comment: Can you share the datasets? One is Stadtteile but I do not recognise the other.
Why did they not match in the first place?

Comment: They had different sources. And the PopDensity one was far off. Also changing the projection did not help. For the shapefile, please see the link I have added. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, that's weird data. Hamburg is in GK zone 3, but this says it is zone 4. I would guess that and/or a wrong datum might be the problem. I would recommend checking if the supplier of the data really knows what they are doing and ask for a UTM 32N or just plain WGS84 dataset instead.

Comment: I saved fixed file in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vCl4PcQaArduWS1cIPG0Wfm4tW2jx1ep/view?usp=sharing . Steps: projected to the same coord. system as correct, repair geometry, delete prj file, applied transformation projective. Something weird with projection itself.

Comment: I used 5 point only. Add more points to improve results.